# Ошибка Composer

Tags: php, composer, openserver

У меня OpenServer. В php.ini allow_url_fopen включил. Когда я ввожу composer install выводит эту ошибку:

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: allow_url_fopen must be enabled in php
  .ini (https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
  failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found)

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] []...

Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в ошибке же написано. Откройте файл php.ini и замените `allow_url_fopen=0` на `allow_url_fopen=1`

Comment: Я заменил(в посте написал). Не работает

Comment: рестартанул после изменений?

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо!